# (plugin commonjs) SyntaxError: Unexpected token when packaging vue component with rollup

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, babeljs, rollupjs

When packaging a Vue component with rollup, this error appears:

**(plugin commonjs) SyntaxError: Unexpected token**
[image]

rollup.config.js:

```
import peerDepsExternal from "rollup-plugin-peer-deps-external";
import resolve from "@rollup/plugin-node-resolve";
import commonjs from "@rollup/plugin-commonjs";
import typescript from "rollup-plugin-typescript2";
import vue from "rollup-plugin-vue";
import {babel} from '@rollup/plugin-babel';

import packageJson from "./package.json";

export default {
    input: "src/index.ts",
    output: [
        {
            format: "cjs",
            file: packageJson.main,
            sourcemap: true
        },
        {
            format: "esm",
            file: packageJson.module,
            sourcemap: true
        }
    ],
    plugins: [babel(), peerDepsExternal(), resolve(), commonjs(), typescript(), vue()]
};
```

button.vue:

```
<template>
  <button>button</button>
</template>
<script lang="ts">
</script>
```

any solution?

**So I found a better way:**

It's better to use [vue-sfc-rollup](https://github.com/team-innovation/vue-sfc-rollup) to package Vue components.

**Update 2023:**
These days Vite is trendy and you can use Vite Lib mode to package Vue components for NPM. [This](https://github.com/ehsan-shv/vite-vue-lib-template) is a starter template that may help you.

Comment: please share a screenshot of the error

Comment: Edited and added screenshot.

Comment: inside the script add `import { defineComponent } from 'vue';export default defineComponent({})` or remove the script section

Comment: Still the same error.

Answer (score 6):

I had a problem like this. Swearing at any html tag in the `<template>`.

```
plugins: [
  vue() //should be the first
  babel(),
  peerDepsExternal(),
  resolve(),
  commonjs(),
  typescript(),
],
```

Watch this [issue](http://github.com/vuejs/rollup-plugin-vue/issues/231).

Comment: This should be an accepted answer... Moving `vue()` plugin before `commonjs()` immediatly fix the issue

Answer (score 0):

The purpose of the `commonjs` plugin is to "convert CommonJS modules to ES6" according to the [docs](https://github.com/rollup/plugins/tree/master/packages/commonjs). Assuming you are using ESM in your source code, there's no need transpile your code with the `commonjs` plugin. The [`exclude` option](https://github.com/rollup/plugins/tree/master/packages/commonjs#exclude) achieves this.

E.g.

```
plugins: [
  // some plugins here
  commonjs({
    exclude: 'src/**',
  }),
  // other plugins here
],
```

As a side note, the `babel` plugin should appear after the `commonjs` plugin in the plugins array, as per the [docs](https://github.com/rollup/plugins/tree/master/packages/babel#using-with-rollupplugin-commonjs), which say:

> When using `@rollup/plugin-babel` with `@rollup/plugin-commonjs` in the same Rollup configuration, it's important to note that `@rollup/plugin-commonjs` must be placed before this plugin in the plugins array for the two to work together properly.